# In ampscript can/how do you set a variable containing a table?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

I'm trying to use the AMPScript to control the layout of the email and I will be using identical info to display in the email for various layouts.

Is there a way to set a variable with html code.

`Set @layout1 = "< table >< tr >< td >%%[if @x == "" then]%%%%[else]%%%%[endif]%%< /td >< /tr >< /table >"`

`%%[if @y == "" than ]%% @layout1 %%[elseif @z == "" than]%%%%[endif]%%`

TIA

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this.

You might take a look at the [AMPScript Function](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_functions/) and [Syntax](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/) help pages.

You can use the [concat()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Concat) function in an AMPScript block:

```
%%[

var @layout, @x

if @whatever == @something then
  set @x = "whoops"
else
  set @x = "whee"
endif

set @layout = concat("<table><tr><td>",@x,"</td></tr></table>")

]%%
%%=v(@layout)=%%
```

You can also embed it in the body of the email and use the [iif()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IIf) function:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
%%=iif(empty(@x),"is empty","is not empty")=%%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Using [outputline()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#OutputLine) is also an option:

```
%%[

var @layout, @x

set @x = "whatever"

outputline(concat("<table><tr><td>"))
outputline(concat("the value is: ",@x))
outputline(concat("</td></tr></table>"))

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I looked into concat and I didn't know how to include double quotes without breaking it so I went with ContentAreaByName and it works.

Comment: Please update your question with your solution, so we can all benefit.

Comment: You can use single quotes for the declaration of AMPscript value and use double quotes inside without breaking it. Eg - SET @y =CONCAT(@x,'<table style="text-align: center">')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I decided to use `ContentAreaByName()` which allows me to make updates to the content without having to search the AMPScript code.

```
%%[if @x == "" then]%%
@subheader = ContentAreaByName("my content...A")
%%[else]%%
@subheader = ContentAreaByName("my content...B")
%%[endif]%%

< body >
%%=v(@subheader)=%%
< /body >
```